# Best forum for chatting with fellow ISVs?

Tags: discussion

maybe I'm ignorant or too far away from the mothership, but I would LOVE an informal, private forum to chat to fellow Salesforce software partners (esp those who make native apps). Even a simple email list or Google Group would be cool. Is there such a thing? If not, would there be interest in one?

The types of things I'd like to discuss would be less technical/Q-and-A style, and more like customer/selling experiences, process issues like security review, pricing and licensing discussions, marketing, upcoming platform changes of note/concern, critical bugs, etc. Ideally it would be a forum that is exclusively for ISVs and focused on ISV-related issues. Surely there are enough of us now for critical mass!

Answer (score 1):

I would also be interested in joining that list, we have recently published our first apps (2 running at the moment), but for now not on the appexchange, I do have some questions about the security review, and what better way to hear them from people that actually went through the whole process.

Comment: Cool, well I'll see if there is already something and if not, I'll set it up. In the meantime, we just had (surprisingly based on some recent stories I heard from other ISV's) smooth sailing through security review and found the security team to be really helpful. Glad to answer any questions either here or over email (jeremy at dashcord dot com).

Comment: I've not heard anything — I'll ask in the MVP chatter circle to see if anybody knows of anything there; I know I'd find it beneficial

Comment: Apparently there was a google group setup but it never took off — just waiting for some more info on it!

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the LinkedIn group [Salesforce.com ISV Partners](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?home=&gid=2031398&trk=anet_ug_hm).

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually already a member of that one. But LinkedIn groups are terrible - poor UI / features, very poor notifications / email digests, most of them are either super-spammy or very low-volume, and overall engagement/participation is very low.

Comment: Agreed. I'd be interested in a more effective forum for chatting with other ISVs too. Just thought I'd mention it.